# Enable copy and paste for a site that doesn't allow it

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I want to say that I very little knowledge of coding so please bear with me. I'm trying to paste in a site that doesn't allow it. This is the link to the javascript that they used to block it, https://mychatdashboard.com/js/messages.js?v=1.3

A friend of mine is helping me with it and he suggested that I put this in the javascript console in the DevTools of Google Chrome,

```
handler = function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); return true; }
document.querySelector('#conversation-content .conversation-message-text').addEventListener('keyup', handler, true)
document.querySelector('#conversation-content .conversation-message-text').addEventListener('input', handler, true)
```

This does solve the problem but it creates another issue. It seems that it interferes with this section of the javascript that I have linked to,

```
* Function to update the messagebox. (Enable/disable send button,
 * change the color class, update the counter)
 * @return  void
```

So what would happen is that when a message is typed in the textbook, there's a character counter at the top which shows how many characters are written. When 80 characters(I think it's 80) are typed, the send button will be enabled so that I can send the message. However, with the javascript code that my friend suggested that I used, it stops the counter from working altogether so the send button never gets highlighted.

Is there any way around this? Please let me know if further clarifications are needed since it's the first time I'm asking a question of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript you're entering into the DevTools console is defining a function named `handler` and then adding it as an event handler for `keyup` and `input` events for a field on the page you're viewing (presumable the chat window textbox).

The way that the handler is defined and attached prevents other events from firing (such as those that enable the send button when you've typed enough characters).

For this sites (and I haven't been able to test it) **instead** of the code you've used you could try running this in the DevTools console (once the page is loaded):

```
restrictCopyPasteByKeyboard = function () { return true; };
```

This ***should*** redefine the function that's preventing you from using paste (I can't test it out because I can't access that site).

Comment: I just tried it but I got an error about 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token true'
This word "true" is underlined in red in DevTools.

Comment: I think the correct thing to put was `window.restrictCopyPasteByKeyboard = function() {}` That's what I replaced it with but it didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Try returning true from the function. I've updated my answer to reflect what I think it should be (you were right, my syntax was wrong!)

Comment: I used that syntax but it didn't work either. I have all but given up. The last thing I tried was this 

`function inputHander(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
}

const elem = document.querySelector('#conversation-content .conversation-message-text');
if (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', inputHander, true);
  elem.addEventListener('input', inputHander, true);
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
  button.disabled = false;
});`

Using that code still disabled the counter.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous way through one can copy contents from Right Click protected sites

1. By disabling browser JavaScript in browser
2. Using Proxy Sites
3. By Using the source code of the site

**Disabling JavaScript in Browsers [Google Chrome]**
In Chrome browser, you can quickly disable JavaScript by going to settings. See the screenshot for better explanation:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQBgn.png)

**Through Viewing Source Code**
f you have to copy the specific text content and you can take care of HTML tags, you can use browser view source options. All the major browser give an option to source of the page, which you can access directly using the format below or by right click. Since, right click is out of question here, we will simply open chrome browser and type: view-source: before the post URl Like

1. view-source:[Enable copy and paste for a site that doesn't allow it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315209/enable-copy-and-paste-for-a-site-that-doesnt-allow-it)
2. Press ctrl+u

And find the paragraph or text you want to copy and then paste it into any text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways of restricting user's ability to copy/paste. In my experience, it's always been a JS function that you can overwrite.

Slight variations of the below have always worked for me:

```
document.getElementById("#ElementWithDisabledPaste").onpaste = null
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this is to enable the designMode in Chrome or Firefox.

1. To open the console window, hit F12 or right-click and select inspect, then navigate to the console tab.
2. `document.designMode = "on"` paste the following snippet.